# PHP automated GET statement to retrieve content

Tags: php, menu, get, switch-statement

I have a menu which creates a GET statement in the url
`<li><a href="?Page=Contact">Contact</a>`. This get is used to get the corresponding content.
As in, the url will look like `?Page=Contact` and than it will load the content from Contact.

Now in another file i have a switch that checks the GET statement in the url.

```
$GetStatement = $ConfigPage->getFormVariable('Page');

switch ($GetStatement){
    case "Home":
        $Content = new ContentHome();
        $ConfigPage->SetProperty('content', $Content);
        break;

    case "Contact":
        $Content = new ContentContact();
        $ConfigPage->SetProperty('content', $Content);
        break;
}
```

Of course there are more cases in this switch, but it's useless to show. Now this switch works flawless. But as my content grows i have to keep adding more cases. And now i am at the point i want this to be automated. Of course i have tried to. but now i have literally no idea how to do this, or what to do.

Edit:

All the different content are in different files. With all unique class name. as you can see above. ContentContact is inside file Contact.php with a class named ContentContact

Comment: So you have a corresponding class `ContentPagename` for each case, and you want to automate their instantiation, or you want to automate the class creation?

Comment: Sorry if that is unclear. Every Content items, as to say, is a different file. And each of these files has a class with the name Content[name of content,]. English is not my native language, sorry. will update the question

Comment: I understand the class structure. I just want to make sure I understand what you hope to automate, and it seems like you just want to avoid the `switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While that's not a very efficient setup (I don't know that I would create one class per page) what you could do is create a function that would do the work of looking for your class for you

```
function loadClass($name) {
    $class_name = 'Content' . $name;
    if(!class_exists($class_name)) return false;
    $class = new $class_name();
    return $class;
}

$class = loadClass($ConfigPage->getFormVariable('Page'));
if($class) $ConfigPage->SetProperty('content', $class);
```

Comment: If you don't have autoloading active you'll need to include the proper file, too

Comment: I would go one step further with validation and keep an array of the acceptable page names to use so it isn't possible to load an unrelated class with a similar name `if (in_array($name, array('Home','Contact','Etc')))`

Comment: I am 2nd year in programming class. And this is somewhat my homework. We were supposed to do exactly as i shown above, with different files with classes inside them for the content. and then a switch to retrieve to content. But while my site keeps growing this is not a very good solution. But i would like to keep it as close as    i was told to do so. Thank you very much for your answer. I will look into it and give you feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
function getContentInstance($stmt) {
   $name = 'Content'.$stmt;
   $path = 'Content/'.str_replace(".", "", $name).'.class.php'; // needs to do even more ...
   if(class_exists($name) {
      return new $name();
   } else {
      if (file_exists($path)) {
         include $path;
         return new $name();
      }
      user_error('Class '.$name.' not found');
   }
}
```